# Can not get key:value from Json array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am sending an request from my node.js server and in the console I am trying to print response data.when i tried to print the Json array.It's Ok.Like this-

```
{"id":1,"name":"Asm Arman","confirmed":0,"confirmation_code":null,"created_at":"2016-09-29 16:34:39","updated_at":"2016-10-04 06:55:30"}
```

Using this-

```
var request = require('request');
var app = require("express")();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
request.get('http://localhost:8000/api', function(err, response, body){

***res.send(body);
console.log(body);***

});
});

app.listen(8081);
```

But I can not print the ***key:value*** pair.I am getting ***undefined***.Here is my Js file

```
var request = require('request');
var app = require("express")();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
request.get('http://localhost:8000/api', function(err, response, body){
var string=JSON.parse(body);
res.send(string.name);
console.log(string.name);

});
});

app.listen(8081);
```

Not only Json.parse() I have also used Json.stringify().But no luck.

Comment: what do your request headers look like? If your content type isn't set to application/json then the request module might not pick up the body properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to parse the body of a request, you need to use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) which isn't installed with Express by default. It will let you handle a body formatted with JSON, URL-encoded form values or text.

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

Then add the following to your code.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// place this before your routes
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: Sir,I have used it.Now,how can I get a key: value pair?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/davidwalsh.name/nodejs-http-request/amp?client=ms-android-google), this is a basic example. I had to look at the docs to see how the get method works, as I thought it was similar to your example where it automatically parsed the response body.

The short and skinny is that request and response objects in node are streams. As data streams in, it triggers the `data` event, which will give you chunks of data you can capture and append together to get the body on the request or response.

So, your code will look something like:

```
let body = '';
http.get('url', (res) => { 
  res.on('data', (chunk) => body += chunk);
  res.on('end', () => { 
    // now the body variable is prepared and you can do something with it 
  }
  res.on('error', err => {
    // Handle errors 
  }
});
```

The data comes in chunks as a buffer, so will need to convert to a string probably, then parse it to use it. So, something like this:

```
JSON.parse(body.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure thats not just the way console.log is outputting your object? Maybe `request` parsed the JSON for you.